Why is static page output not visible on the network?
I have a project that I created with Nextjs 14 and I have an about page in this project. There is an info component in the about page. When I go to the about routing from the home page at the beginning, there are two requests in the Network tab. The text("info-component") in the info component is not in their response. Where exactly does this text come from? Even if it was created with ssg at the time of build, shouldn't I see it in the network when I go to /about?



The text "info container" in the InfoContainer component of your Next.js project is part of the static content rendered by React. Here's how it works:
Pre-rendering (SSG or SSR): Next.js will pre-render pages at build time (SSG) or on request (SSR). The InfoContainer component and its content, such as "info container," is part of that pre-rendered HTML.
Hydration: When you navigate to the /about route from the home page, the content (like the "info container" text) has already been pre-rendered and embedded within the HTML of the page. That's why you don't see it as part of the network request because it's not dynamically fetched—it was either part of the initial HTML or rendered directly from the pre-built static assets.
JavaScript Bundle: After the HTML is served to the browser, Next.js will hydrate the page with React. The component code, including the "info container" text, comes from the JavaScript bundle rather than additional network requests. The JavaScript bundle was already loaded when you navigated to /about.
So, even if the page is statically generated (SSG), the actual network request you see would typically be for the JavaScript that rehydrates the component but not the static text itself. This is why you don't see the text "info container" in the network responses when navigating between routes.

You said "it was either part of the initial HTML or it was directly processed from pre-generated static assets" but it is not in either the html or js that came before.

return (

 
)